# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm almost finished step 11 on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html .
There is something wrong with my tags though, i keep getting this when trying to create a new post.

**ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#create**

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tags_attributes
Rails.root: /Users/david/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:46:in `new'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:46:in`create'
Request

Parameters:

```
    {"post"=>{"name"=>"David",
    "content"=>"Foobar",
    "title"=>"Programmer",
    "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Tea,
    Cake"}}},
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "commit"=>"Create Post",
    "authenticity_token"=>"MhvAkAPcAey1Z4YXy7nKFmW/wETlu+USSvWOEBBN4po="}
```

I've been over and over every line of code containing the implementation of tags, and i can't figure it out.  Some guidance to what i should be looking for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model, you need to add `tag_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` call.

For example :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tags_attributes
end
```

If you already call it once, you can either add this field as an argument of the method, or make a second call. Both options are equivalent.

Having to specify all accessible parameters wasn't a default until a few months.
This guide has been updated to reflect the change of default. But the new version hasn't been deployed yet, this is why it's not specified.

See [Security: Mass Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures)

Comment: class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title, :tags_attributes


adding :tags_attributes to my post model worked.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, 
In your PostsController model add all attributes used in the form such as,

```
 class PostsController < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :content, :title
   ...
   ...
 end
```

it works for me.