# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I get a ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error  when I try to running my app to save the login and password details. 
got the following error

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, password, password_confirmation, salt
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in`create'

here is the code from the control file

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623274/1530410) and credits for [Damien Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122080/damien-mathieu)

In your model, you need to add `tag_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` call.

For example :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tags_attributes
end
```

If you already call it once, you can either add this field as an argument of the method, or make a second call. Both options are equivalent.

Having to specify all accessible parameters wasn't a default until a few months.
This guide has been updated to reflect the change of default. But the new version hasn't been deployed yet, this is why it's not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the attr_accessible parameters in your model. Check out [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) for more information regarding attr_accessbile and what it protects from.

Answer (score 0):

Like waldyr.ar said, also you can use attr_protected